# Microsoft Graph Accessing Room Calendars

Tags: calendar, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access some room calendars to create a booking monitoring app and are hitting some weird issues.

When checking some rules with the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/RoomEmail@domain.com/events?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,organizer,attendees,start,end,location
```

For some rooms this returns the data you would expect (booking information etc)

On other rooms (majority of them) it just returns a Failure status code of 503

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "ErrorInternalServerTransientError",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred. Try again later.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "31c78608-9a54-4927-9ad5-0ec3d36aedcf",
        "date": "2017-11-27T16:22:17"
    }
}
```

I've check the permissions and license on all the room mailboxes and they have the same. They are also all classed as RoomMailboxes in office365

I have also applied the following permissions on the user that is running the query. As per documentation: [Permission Doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events#permissions)

> Calendars.Read
>   Calendars.ReadWrite
>   Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing this consistently or is this a transient issue? Is it the same rooms that return this error message each time?

Comment: It's a consistent problem, the rooms that are working works all the time vice versa. As I said I also cannot find any difference in lincense or permissions on the different Rooms